What caused the damages on my tree?
Gardening newbie here. I live in New Jersey.
I have this big tree in my backyard. It was planted probably more than 10 years ago. I have found multiple wounds. I see some clear liquid on those wounds. I have taken a few pictures. What could be the cause of those wounds? Do I need to do anything?
Also, can you identify the tree?
Please let me know if more pictures are needed.






It eyeballs from this distance as a probable White Pine, but verifying the number of needles in a bunch would confirm or deny. The clear liquid would be sap (pitch, for resinous evergreens, but pitch is sap.)

Have you had any work done by an alleged tree service? One explanation would involve a major faux pas by a tree climber who should know better.
